# GParted taking forever

Tags: live-cd, gparted

I'm trying to install ubuntu 12.10 from DVD. Every time I try, I get an I/O error. I've tried replacing the RAM, with no change.

I decided I'd try to create a clean HD by booting into liveCD and then running Gparted. However-- gparted just runs with the "Scanning all devices" message forever-- though running `fdisk -l` from the terminal does find the drive fine.

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens because you have misconfigured your bios to think you have a floppy drive when you don't.  Fix your bios setting.

Comment: thanks-- can you be more explicit? Which bios setting would affect this?

Comment: hmm-- ok, searched the bios, indeed there was a floppy drive supposedly in the system, which I disabled. Saved bios settings and rebooted, same issue in Gparted.

Comment: trying to clear the disk-- getting `Input/output error during read on /dev/sda` then `Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input / output error`

Comment: @user101289, then it sounds like your hard disk is failing.  Check the SMART status in the disk utility.